# Why some Large number (around 100 digit) can factor out very fast?

Tags: prime-factoring, number-theory

I am new to number theory, I am trying to prime factor large numbers in around 100 digit numbers.

like my program factor out a 93 digit number in 30min while a 116 digit number that took computer few days.

however, there is a 104 digit number i work on 13270693758489295980223043261833153409168505210538146384653262578584663296471619841442958585315929292397

the result come out instantly

I wonder why this number able to factor out so fast. what condition it must satisfy to able to factor out very fast and easy.

Comment: Look at what that factorization *is*, and trace through what your program does with each of those inputs.

Answer (score 0):

The 47-digit factor 15630142427492468388372081926250991439041076399 is smooth and easily found by Pollard's *p* − 1 method with B = 2000; the remaining cofactor is prime.

Comment: Thanks, i think that factor as p-1 will be a number only have small prime factors. so it is able to be fast found by p-1

Answer (score 0):

Some primes have lots of small factors so they get eliminated fast, then our new number is a lot smaller and that gets factored quickly so...